# Feature update on production server

Tags: sharepoint

I'm not an experienced sharepoint developer and i have the following scenario here. I've been working on a sharepoint solution that has 4 packages. After we have done the development, we tried to deploy the wsp's on the production server. But something went wrong. When i was updating the first solution package, i got the following error message:

```
Directory "X" associated with feature 'XXX’ in the solution is used by feature 'XXX' installed in the farm. All features must have unique directories
```

I've googled a lot and the recurrent solution is to retract the solution package e add it again, and maybe delete the feature folder. But i've been wondering why i can't just search for the Id of the features in the production environment and hard code this Id on my solution, in the template xml of the feature. What is the best approach to follow?